# ReactJS component to upload a file to a Spring MVC/Data-REST server

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, browser, reactjs

I have been searching for a while for a `ReactJS` `component` to allow you to upload a file from a `browser` and have it saved to the server `ReactJS` is running on.

I have found various `component`s for `drag and drop` etc and `superagent` for possibly saving the file to the server but I figured someone might have created a `component` for all of this?

The back end is a Java application using Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA and Spring Data REST.

Does anyone know of one or a tutorial on setting up a basic way to save the file to the server?

**Solution**

In the end I used part of the solution below with dropzone and superagent and then utilized the Spring guide (https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

**Uploader component**

```
'use strict';

const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

const log = require('./log'); // logger to enable debug alerts

// import the components
const Dropzone = require('react-dropzone');
const request = require('superagent');

//'application/java-archive'
class Uploader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dropHandler = this.dropHandler.bind(this);
  }

  dropHandler(file) {
    var jsonFile = new FormData();
    jsonFile.append('file', file[0]);
    jsonFile.append('name', file[0].name);

    request.post('/upload')
    .send(jsonFile)
    .end(function(err, resp) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      return resp;
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Dropzone disableClick={false} multiple={false} accept={'application/java-archive'} onDrop={this.dropHandler}>
        < div > Drop a Appium Jar, or click to add. < /div >
      </Dropzone>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Uploader
```

**FileUploadController**

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String provideUploadInfo() {
        return "You can upload a file by posting to this same URL.";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String>  handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
        if (name.contains("/")) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body("Folder separators not allowed.");
        } else if (name.contains("/")) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body("Relative pathnames not allowed.");
        } else if (!name.endsWith(".jar")) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body("File type not allowed.  Must be a Jar file type ending in '.jar'.");
        }

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return ResponseEntity.ok("File " + name + " uploaded.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body("You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It really depends where you plan to store the file / what your backend looks like.  I would start by finding an ajax accessible method of saving the file.  From there, building a react component to execute the ajax call is fairly trivial and not something you'll likely need an external component's help in achieving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to do this through your server. What kind of backend are you using?  If you are using Node.js there is an npm module called [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) that saves files to your server. I talk about it some in my blogpost about [react dropzones](https://djizco.wordpress.com/2016/04/15/how-to-create-a-dropzone-in-reactnode-js/). Without more info on your backend its hard to say exactly what you need to do.